# Gesture Detector is not working React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

i am new to React Native. I was following a tutorial about making a bottomsheet from scratch however i have an issue with

```
const gesture= Gesture.Pan().onUpdate((event)=>{
        console.log(event.translationX);
    });
```

It isn't detecting the gesture and not showing anything in the terminal.

this the code of the  screen that should render the BottomSheet component:

CongeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../../components/Header';    
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Host, Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import {
   SafeAreaView,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   useColorScheme,
   View,
   Image,
 TextInput,
 TouchableOpacity
 } from 'react-native';
 
 import {
   Colors,
   DebugInstructions,
   LearnMoreLinks,
   ReloadInstructions,
 } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import BottomSheet from '../../components/BottomSheet'
import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper';


 const CongeScreen: () => Node = ({navigation}) => {
   return (
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
          <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header
          titre={'Mes congés'}
          />

          <View style={styles.viewEmpty}>
          <Text style={styles.textEmpty}>Vous n'avez pas encore de congés</Text>
          <Image style={{marginTop:35}}
            source={require('../../assets/calendar-xmark-solid.png')} />

          </View>
          <View styles={styles.line} />
        </View> 
        <BottomSheet />  
</GestureHandlerRootView>
     </SafeAreaView>
   );
 };
 
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   body:{ flex:1,
   backgroundColor:'#202020',
   fontFamily:'Montserrat-Regular',
   color:'#E9E9E9',
   },   
   container:{
    paddingVertical:60, 
    paddingHorizontal:20,
    },
    viewEmpty:{
      alignItems:'center'
    },
    textEmpty:{
      color:'#484848',
      fontFamily:'Montserrat-Bold',
      fontSize:16
    }
   });
 
 export default CongeScreen;
```

this the BottomSheet Component

BottomSheet.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions,StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const { height:SCREEN_HEIGHT }= Dimensions.get('window');   
import { Host, Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const BottomSheet =() =>{


    const gesture= Gesture.Pan().onUpdate((event)=>{
        console.log(event.translationX);
    })

    return (
<Portal>
        <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
    <Animated.View style={styles.bottomSheetContainer}>
    <View style={styles.line} />

        
            
            
    </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
        </Portal>
    )
}

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    bottomSheetContainer:{
        height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        width:'100%',
        backgroundColor:'white',
        position:'absolute',
        top:SCREEN_HEIGHT/1.5,
        borderRadius:25,

    },
    line:{
        
        height:3,
        width:50,
        backgroundColor:'grey',
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginVertical:10,
        borderRadius:2

        
}
});

export default BottomSheet;
```

These are my dependecies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  }
```

and this babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
],
};
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: have you found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a collapsable=false property in the first child view, like this:

```
<GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
    <Animated.View style={styles.bottomSheetContainer} collapsable={false}>
       ...
    </Animated.View>
</GestureDetector>
```

The explanation is this: Views that are only used to layout their children or otherwise don't draw anything may be automatically removed from the native hierarchy as an optimization.

So, the GestureDetector's child view is being removed and it might be producing this issue.